# Getting ParseException while migrating date column in TALEND

Tags: talend

I have a column in old oracle DB in which values are present as "10/27/2014 10:14:26" and i want it to migrate in my new DB in 2 column viz. date and time. I have written the following code in tMap

TalendDate.parseDate("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'","row1.BLOCK_DATE")

but on running the job i am getting following excepition:

```
    Exception in component tMap_1
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "row1.BLOCK_DATE"
    at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:864)
    at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:808)
    at zain.transfer_0_1.transfer.tOracleInput_3Process(transfer.java:999)
    at zain.transfer_0_1.transfer.runJobInTOS(transfer.java:1534)
    at zain.transfer_0_1.transfer.main(transfer.java:1391)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "row1.BLOCK_DATE"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at routines.TalendDate.parseDate(TalendDate.java:850)
    ... 4 more
```

someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove double quotes and pass the column name as it is, it will work. use like this

`TalendDate.parseDate("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",row1.BLOCK_DATE)`